# how to exclude a jar from an sdk in gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Hi guys I am trying to exclude a jar libs from this vungle sdk `compile 'com.admost.sdk:vungle:5.3.0'`, the common libs that are in the sdk and I am using which causing the prob are `dagger-2.7`, `gson-2.7` and `rxjava-1.2.0` I have tried all the ways I found all did not work.
the error I am getting when building the project is

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForStagingDebug'.
>   java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\Geeky\Work\UFL\UFL-Android\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\staging\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\bisho.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\vungle-5.3.0.aar\b93710fa3315099ee82cab738c995134\jars\libs\dagger-2.7.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [dagger-2.7.jar:dagger/Reusable.class]))

Comment: Gradle typically handles this fine on its own. Unless you have jar files in your own project, that's when you see the error

Comment: actually yeah I have one jar file so is there any solution?

Comment: Well, that depends what that JAR is. Does it have a corresponding Gradle `compile` line? Does that JAR file itself contain any of the libraries you listed?

Answer (score 1):

Select Project instead of android in the left pane window. See the image below.

Delete the jar if not using. Remove the reference from gradle too. It should work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
You can build this sdk like below example:


    compile("com.github.vungle:vungle-android-sdk:5.3.0") {
            exclude group: 'com.google.dagger', module: 'dagger'
            exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module: 'gson'   
            exclude group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', module: 'rxjava'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**To find duplicate dependencies or its required dependencies, you can visualize library dependencies in tree. Execute gradle command as below.**

run gradlew in Windows as below. 
**gradlew -q dependencies yourProject:dependencies --configuration compile**

The command result will show you human-readable tree hierarchy of all dependencies as below.

compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.2
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.1
+--- com.squareup:otto:1.3.6
+--- in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.10
+--- com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3
+--- com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3
+--- org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.+ -> 6.5.87
+--- project :yourProject
|    +--- com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6
|    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.5
|    |    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
+--- project :facebook
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1
|              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.1 -> 22.2.0

You can see overriden dependencies and decide in mind which ones should be avoided. 
In above example, last line com.android.support:support-annotations presents overriden from 22.1.1 to 22.2.0 internally.
**To avoid duplicates**,you can add exclude clauses in each project build.gradle file.

compile('com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3') {
exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
compile('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
}
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.+')
{
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```